# How to do SUM in a Conditional statement in EXCEL?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have been working on this problem for quite some time and cannot wrap my head around the best possible approach to the issue.

**Project Question:** How many tickets did an organization submit within their first 30 days? 60? 180? and how many tickets were submitted after 180 days post sign up?

The issue I am finding myself stuck on is trying to sum two (possibly 3 or more) columns that fall under the date difference of >60 and <180 days.

I have tried using long, long IFs statement to measure the datedifference, however, it proved to be incorrect in some of the accounts...

`=IFS((AND((AND(($T$1-C6)>60,($T$1-C6)<180)),(AND(($U$1-C6)>60,($U$1-C6)<180)))),SUM(T6:U6)... (AND((AND(($T$1-C6)>60,($T$1-C6)<180)),(AND(($U$1-C6)>60,($U$1-C6)<180)), (AND(($V$1-C6)>60,($V$1-C6)<180)), (AND(($W$1-C6)>60,($W$1-C6)<180)), (AND(($X$1-C6)>60,($X$1-C6)<180)), (AND(($Y$1-C6)>60,($Y$1-C6)<180)),(AND(($Y$1-C6)>60,($Y$1-C6)<180)))), SUM(T6:Y6))`

For 30 days, and >180 days, my code seems to work at a 99% accuracy:
`=IFERROR(IFS(($S$1-C4)>= 180, SUM(S4:AA4), ($T$1-C4)>= 180, SUM(T4:AA4),... ($AA$1-C4)>= 180, AA4),0)`

I have tried the same thing for >30;<60 and >60;<180 days however, it is not giving me an accurate sum of the columns that fall under the required date difference.

Has anyone out there have done a similar project to this? I have attached a sample data set onto this posting.

[Data set via Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QUq8LAk8BDAI2ZzKdpcytOBOIyvFkP1kBkIA04jGttg/edit?usp=sharing)

Thank you so much in advance,
Dan

Comment: 30, 60, 180 from which date? Current date or from sign up date?

Comment: @Harun24HR The date difference would be from Q2 2018 to the sign up date and so forth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an array formula. In your example, it might look like this:

```
=SUM(IF(($E$1:$M$1-B4>0) * ($E$1:$M$1-B4<30);E4:M4;0)) - for 30 days
=SUM(IF(($E$1:$M$1-B4>0) * ($E$1:$M$1-B4<60);E4:M4;0)) - for 60 days
=SUM(IF(($E$1:$M$1-B4>0) * ($E$1:$M$1-B4<180);E4:M4;0)) - for 180 days
=SUM(IF(($E$1:$M$1-B4>180);E4:M4;0))                    - for >180 days
```

Array formulas can be entered after typing by pressing Ctrl + Shift + Enter

Comment: It's my guess that the difference between the sign up date (range B4: B12) and the range E1: M1 should be used to calculate days. You can change it to the dates you want.

Answer (score -1):

I basically used your book and built from there. 
See the formulas under the days section. Does this work for you? 
https://1drv.ms/x/s!AonuHfj4BhiMxzQlslhVrTmwM0Xy

Comment: Got it, thats an interesting approach. This could work! Do you have a way where instead of having a few extra columns to define the date differences, could we insert (quarter date - sign up date) in the formula you created?

Comment: check the formulas in sheet 'option 2'. By the way, just realized that option 2 calculations are more accurate.

Comment: ah, thank you! is there a reason why you wrote ""<="&$B4+R$3"?  I wouldn't have thought of it...

Comment: of course ! that's flattering. The formula says "less than [sign up date]+ [30,60,90,+inf] respectively". In other words, let's use [sign up date] +30 as an example, if it is less than [sign up date ] + 30 then ticket was created within 30 days of sign up. Same logic for 60, 90, and so forth. thanks again !

Comment: by the way, if you liked my answer please upvote it and mark it as the solution. Thank you!